# Google Maps API возвращает пустой ответ

Tags: php, google-maps-api

Не могу разобраться как работает Google Maps API.
Я пользуюсь декодером адресов, если ввожу с браузера следующее:

> [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=г.Москва](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%D0%B3.%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0)

Всё OK: сработает, покажет координаты. Как только переношу все на сервер — не хочет работать. Я уже зарегистрировал на доменное имя `key`. Ввожу его.

Получаю данные примерно так:

```
$url_map_api = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$address."&key=KEY_APP";
$content = file_get_contents($url_map_api);
```

Раньше ругался, что ключ не тот — сейчас вроде зарегистрировал КЛЮЧ, но ответ пустой (ничего не возвращает). Кто работал? Что ещё надо настроить?

Я уже отключил v3 в Google Console, включил только v2 — всё равно ничего (пустой ответ). :(((

Comment: Там на самом деле `"&key=KEY_APP";` написано, или вы просто это написали вместо настоящего ключа?

Comment: Вместо настоящего ключа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю что `file_get_contents` не принимает с другого домена + https. Вам тут нужен CURL!

Try the following script to see if there is an https wrapper available for your php scripts.

```
$w = stream_get_wrappers();
echo 'openssl: ',  extension_loaded  ('openssl') ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'http wrapper: ', in_array('http', $w) ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'https wrapper: ', in_array('https', $w) ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'wrappers: ', var_dump($w);
```

the output should be something like

```
openssl: yes
http wrapper: yes
https wrapper: yes
wrappers: array(11) {
  [...]
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Спасибо, это реально помогло.